# 1/x violates DCP rules in CVXPY

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, cvxpy

I want to solve a non-linear optimization problem using `cvxpy`. I get a `DCP Error` when introducing `1/x` in the constraints, where `x` is a variable.

For instance such a code leads to a `DCP Error`

```py
import cvxpy

x = cvxpy.Variable(1)

obj = cvxpy.Maximize(x)
cst = [1/x >= 1]

prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, cst)
opt_val = prob.solve()
```

Expected result is `x=1`. Also `1/x` is obviously convex so I don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: Look at the error message `DCPError("Can only divide by a scalar constant.")`. You are dividing by a variable.

Comment: I do not have this prompt. Mine says "DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules."
EDIT : as it is allowed to divide by a variable in CVXOPT, I would assume it is also possible using CVXPY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding an optionnal parameter to prob.solve() :

```py
import cvxpy

x = cvxpy.Variable(1)

obj = cvxpy.Maximize(x)
cst = [1/x >= 1]

prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, cst)
opt_val = prob.solve(qcp=True)
opt_val
```

Returns x = 1 as expected.